# Is it possible to get tweets of the people I follow

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I have noticed the common way to get the user's tweets is using timeline() but I want to get tweets of people I follow which twitter calls friends.

Comment: yes, there is a friends api endpoint

Comment: Thanks. I found that I can use the friends api to get friends, then loop each of them to get each follower's timeline.